# Is the dual of a projective module always projective?

Tags: modules, homological-algebra, projective-module

I'm able to prove it for finitely generated modules, by appealing to the characterization of a projective module as a summand of a free module, and the fact that finite-rank free modules are isomorphic to their duals.

Is it true for all modules? I have seen seemingly conflicting evidence both ways (mostly against, by observations like the dual of the direct sum of countably many copies of $\mathbb{Z}$ is not free (but could it still be projective?).)

Comment: No, it can't be projective because for abelian groups, projective is equivalent to free (since a subgroup of a free abelian group is always free, hence a direct summand of a free abelian group is itself free abelian).

Comment: Okay, so then let's move away from $\mathbb{Z}$-modules to arbitrary $\mathbb{R}$-modules.

Comment: Oh, right, I guess that's a counterexample then.

Comment: This is rather curious. You get several Google hits for the phrase "dual of a projective module is projective" but I guess they all work under additional assumptions...?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: It's true for finitely generated (as noted by Bean); that would account for lots of Google hits in and of itself.

Comment: I got some other special cases that had geometric interpretations, I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $P = \bigoplus_{\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Z}$. Then the dual $\text{Hom}(\bigoplus_{\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z})$ is not free.

Assume it is projective,and hence there is some $B$ such that $\text{Hom}(\bigoplus_{\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}) \oplus B$ is free. As Arturo points out subgroups of free Abelian groups are free and so $\text{Hom}(\bigoplus_{\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z})$ must be free - which is a contradiction.

Comment: I think the hardest part would be to show that $\prod_{\mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z}$ not free!

Comment: Looks like there's a proof here http://crazyproject.wordpress.com/2011/05/03/direct-products-of-free-modules-need-not-be-free/

Comment: You can also take a look at [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/74829/660).